# How to structure the programming process?

Tags: java, android

Are there any good tutorials or other sources that describe well the -process- of creating a program (for java android, but more general is fine too)? Tutorials are generally "this is my idea, and now I'll show how to techically implement it", but that's not really what I want.

I have an idea, what do I need to do to implement it? I try to use different tutorials and tools (like UML class diagrams, case diagrams, etc), but it's difficult to "get them to work together". Although I'm learning how to use them, it's at a pretty slow pace and I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel over and over again.

I'm looking for a description that can tell me, preferably in comprehensible steps/phases, what building blocks I need to create and how to structure the creation process efficiently. It doesn't matter if it's complex or simple, just something that nudges me in the right direction, so to speak.

Comment: Use cases, an analysis, models, ... It all depends on how you (prefer to) work. But this is not related to Java or android, so why do you add those tags?

Comment: @Fred let me know if the answer was helpful

Comment: @Stultuske Well, that's what I'm working with, so in case there are solutions that are specific, that's what I'm interested in

Comment: Efficient implementation requires expertise, and there's no shortcut to expertise.

Comment: @Antlersoft I'm not interested in shortcuts, just the most efficient way of learning the process. Extrapolating from others' works doesn't feel like it (in this case) since they're too specific. I mean, it's an individual process, but surely there's are some conceptual descriptions out there of how to go about programming, no?

Comment: Based on my experience in most places, it goes like this: boss says to go program something, quick, quick, it's an emergency.  You code really hard for the least amt. of time needed to get something working to the point where they say it's good enough, then the testing "phase" is pretty much fudged and quick, quick, put it into prod.  Then it crashes and the manager immediately distances him- or herself as fast as possible from the effort and everyone tries to move on to something else and pretend everything is OK.  [OK, so I'm a little jaded. :) ]

Answer (score 2):

You're right. There is no need to start from scratch. I use this tool to speed things up, try it out.

For UML flowcharts use this https://www.gliffy.com/

For mockups/wireframes use this https://ninjamock.com/

**Although there are a ton of other tools, I use these as they are popular and fast**.

Android development is user interface driven. Therefore we do the UI first (assuming the UI is finalized and icons and colors(theme) have been picked).
After that we start to write the code to populate the fields. This is because this is how it'll be taught to you. It's not documented anywhere, but any tutorial or book will keep the same approach.

Comment: Thanks! What I'm looking for isn't so much the tools themselves, rather a guide about "this is how the tools are implemented together when programming".

Comment: like from the mock ups you want to implement them

Comment: Well, I know that a class diagram can easily be converted into code, and similar things, but I more want to know in what order to do things. Like, do I start with layout and fill in functions, or do I figure out which functions I need and then create the layout? Is there a description of the whole process in that way?

Comment: check my updated answer if you feel something is missing let me know